# Javascript scaling an array of timestamps in a responsive div to total 100

Tags: javascript

I have a project where I am trying to visualize what my pet is doing when I'm not home. I have N# of events in allEvents array. The problem is I want to scale up the events that are smaller just so I can see them in this responsive div. 
For example: 
App Starts: 1sec 
Pet traveling 50sec 
Pet is in Room 40min 
If keeping scaling this example, the pet would be in the room for 99% of this thing, and the rest of the events would be very tough to read on a screen. 
Let me know if I can clarify anything.

```js
const allEvents = [{type: "start", ts: 1620057602}, {type: "traveling",ets: 1620057632, ts: 1620057614}, {type: "traveling", ets: 1620057632, ts: 1620057624}, {type: "room", ets: 1620057991, ts: 1620057632}, {type: "traveling", ets: 1620058004, ts: 1620057991}, {type: "room", ets: 1620058142, ts: 1620058004}, {type: "room", ets: 1620058286, ts: 1620058142}, {type: "traveling", ets: 1620058318, ts: 1620058286}, {type: "traveling", ets: 1620058318, ts: 1620058291}, {type: "fin", ts: 1620058325}]


    const globalStart = 1620057600;
    const globalEnd = 1620058325;
    const totalTime = globalEnd - globalStart;

let totalWidth = 0;
  const aggeratedEvents = allEvents.map((val, i) => {
      const start = val.ts;
      const end = val.ets || null;
      const total = (!end) ? 0 : (end - start);

      let percent_of_total_time = Math.round((total / totalTime) * 100);

      // Help!
      // Padd any elements of 2 or less to 2?
      // just so they show up as part of this horizontal line
      if(percent_of_total_time <= 2){
        percent_of_total_time = 2;
      }
      totalWidth += percent_of_total_time;

      return {
        ...val,
        'duration': total,
        'width': Math.round(percent_of_total_time)
      }
    });


/** Append data */
aggeratedEvents.forEach(el => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", el.type);
    div.style.width = el.width + "%";
    div.innerHTML = el.type;
  document.getElementById('elements').appendChild(div)
})

document.getElementById("totalWidth").innerHTML = 'Total Width: ' + totalWidth;
```

```css
#traveling{
 background-color:pink;
 display: inline-block;
}
#room{
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
#elements{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#start, #fin{
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="elements"><!--Dynamically append colors --></div>
    <div id="totalWidth"></div> <span>Where this should be 100</span>
```

Comment: What is N#? I don't recognise the term.

Comment: I updated it @VLAZ. I used N# to symbolize an array of varying length.